# Migrating a project in asp.net to drupal

Tags: asp.net, drupal, migration, data-migration, database-migration

I am tryin to rebuild a website designed in asp.net.But,being an informative site it has a lot of content in it which i dnt want to input to the database manually.

can ne1 help me out with any drupal module to migrate the asp.net data in sql server to mysql db in form of drupal architecture??

say for example a page in asp.net is displaying data from a form.Can i migrate it in form of cck and get the page data as nodes table.

Answer (score 2):

The comparison table of all available solutions is useful, but I would strongly recommend the [Migrate](http://drupal.org/project/migrate) module for this. It should work with MS SQL source data (I've only used it with MySQL and Postgres source databases), and is quite flexible in regards to mapping the source data to the Drupal schema. For Drupal 6, it supports most CCK field types (including images and files), and for Drupal 7 it supports the new Field API quite nicely.

The approach that the module takes, allows you to do continuous migrations such that if your source ASP site is still adding or changing content, it will keep track of what has been migrated, and even allows updating of previously migrated content.

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://groups.drupal.org/node/21338) have a comparison table of the main modules that may help you importing the data into Drupal. But keep in mind that you'll have some work to do before actually importing, since there's no magical way for Drupal to map the columns of your database to the Drupal columns.